# Custom editor will not load the file in exported eclipse rcp product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse RCP with my custom editor.

Everything works fine when I run it within the eclipse environment ( by selecting "Launch an Eclipse application"). My editor opens the relevant files correctly.

However, when I export the product, the editor does not load the file, although it seems to be correctly initialized and no error message appears (no log files are created).

The product has been developed using Eclipse 3.x API based plug-ins and RCP applications on top of the Eclipse 4.x platform. I am running the product on Kubuntu 14.04.

I have already the org.eclipse.equinox and org.eclipse.osgi added in the contents of the product.

Are there any extra dependencies that should be added in order to export the product?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure there is no '.log' file in the workspace '.metadata' directory (these are hidden files on Linux)

Comment: You are right! There is a .log file in the workspace and it helped me solve the problem. A package import could not be resolved. 

Thanks a lot!